# How do I put bookmarks into a single folder on a Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-os

How do I make folders and put all the bookmarks into different folders, sorted by category (e.g. School, work, social, etc.)? I made a new folder for school, but I don't see it and don't know how to put all school bookmarks within it.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, on the far right, below the 'X' close button is a triple line. Select the button, then move the mouse over Bookmarks, then select Bookmark Manager (or as a shortcut press CTRL-SHIFT-O). Now you can move the bookmarks and folders where ever you like.

Comment: Your answer tells me nothing. How? Where? How do I put similar files in the same folder to have fewer bookmarks? How do I create folders? How do I move files into them? I need step-by-step instructions. Yours is too vague.

Comment: It works like most File Managers in the common operating systems. If you need assistance with that, then you are a neophyte.